# Mission Control bug on Mountain Lion: Dragging Windows to Desktops Fails Regularly

Tags: macos, mission-control, bug

When I activate Mission Control and try to drag drag, say, two windows to another desktop, the first drag works fine. I can drag the window to the other desktop's thumbnail, which darkens, and then release the mouse, and the window moves to that desktop just as it should.

When I try to drag the second window, however, the recipient space won't darken—it doesn't register that I'm dragging the window over it—and when I release the mouse button, the window will snap back to its original position as though I'd dragged it to some other part of the screen.

When I initiate another drag on the second window (the third drag total) it'll work properly. Then, I'll drag another window and it won't work. It occurs every other time I drag a window, with perfect regularity, as far as I can tell.

Other points:

- Non-working drags doesn't have to be over a space for the next drag to work. I could drag a window an inch, release it, and then pick it up and drag it to another desktop just fine.
- The "new desktop" button never seems to suffer from this problem.
- The problem also occurs on the guest account.

Any ideas how to fix it, or why it's happening? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can also reproduce it on 10.8. I guess the most likely way to get it fixed is to file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: It's not fixed in 10.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

This has been killing me, too. But I went into the MC preferences pane and unchecked "Group windows by application." It worked.

Comment: You're right—this does fix the issue. Though I do prefer the grouped look, I guess it's back to this Leopard-ish mode for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, there is a keyboard shortcut which allows moving windows between desktops. All you need to do is to to go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Mission Control and enable Switch to Desktop 1, 2 ,... n Desktops you have.

Then in order to move the window you need to move your mouse to start dragging the window and then use Switch to Desktop keyboard shortcut.